# Wordle: is 4 all-gray guesses possible?

Tags: wordle

Obviously it is not possible, using optimal word guessing, to have 5 completely gray guesses.
But is it possible to have 4 completely gray guesses before getting the correct word?

Put another way, are there 5 valid words in the Wordle dictionary that use 25 different letters (or 24, if the solution word has a duplicate letter)?

If there are not, how many gray letters are possible in the 4th guess?

Comment: I assume here we need to assume that all guesses have no repeat letters? Also note that it could be 23 different letters among 5 words (the solution is among them) if the solution is TENET.

Comment: @justhalf that is an assumption that I made, yes, but if there are words in the wordle dictionary that support it, I would like to know how many unique letters are involved in a 4-all-grey-guess arrangement.

Comment: From the question Hexomino linked, the set "vibex, fjord, nymph, waltz, gucks" works, with either waltz/fjord/nymph as the solution (the other 2 can be found in the guess list of Wordle dictionary, and these three are possible solutions in Wordle dictionary). So I guess let's close this question.

Comment: @hexomino that question does indeed appear to include a few viable sets of words.

Comment: Incidentally, it would be possible, for a few words in the Wordle answer list, to make six all-gray guesses in Hard Mode and still not know what the correct word was.